# window.focus not working upon browser close , but working well when trigger via button

Tags: javascript, html, popup, window

While I'm successfully able to switch focus to Parent window while closing the child window using the close button, Unable to do the same while performing the close using the browser close button. Steps are per below.
1. Click Try it in parent window.
2. Open another tab in browser.
3.1 Click the Close Me button in the child window.
4. Focus successfully navigate to Parent window.
3.2 Click the browser close button.
4. Focus not navigating to Parent window.

Browser using : Chrome, Would be happy to get a generic way for all the browser.

**parent.html**

```
    <html>
            <html>
            <body>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
            <script>
            function myFunction() {
              window.name="parent";
              var myWindow = window.open('child.html', "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
              myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
            }
            </script>

            </body>
   </html>
```

**Child.html**

```
<html>
<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>
<button onclick="closeWindow()">Close Me</button>

<script>
    function closeWindow() {
        window.close();
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        var goBack = window.open('', 'parent');
        goBack.focus();
    }
</script>
<html>
```

Comment: `document.write` in the click handler function creates a new document with a new name for the window. Don't use `dw` to ... well to anything.

Comment: Notice, that pop-up windows have [`opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) property which refers to the window opened the pop-up.

Comment: Since you write `2. Open another tab in browser.`, why not use an actual extra tab by using target `_blank` instead of overwriting the parent tab so you don't have to reopen the parent tab to begin with? As written in the docs, focussing a window that was reopened by using window.open() and a tab name may not work correctly depending on the browser.

Comment: @Teemu Tried childwindow.opener.focurs() but didn't work.

Comment: How about just `opener.focus();` in the pop-up?

Comment: @Teemu Didn't work

Comment: window.open( '','parent').focus() works when the close the window.onbeforeunload is initiated by the closeWindow method , and not working with browser close event.

Comment: Ehh ... If you're closing a browser how does it even matter?

Comment: @Teemu window.onbeforeunload event supposedly run before the window close, In debug I could see the code executing as well. But somehow focus is not changing to the first window.

Comment: @Teemu http://neosw6.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ Try here

Comment: On the linked page, no matter how I'd close the pop-up, the opener is always focused. FireFox 64.02. Maybe focusing is also a browser-dependent, as Shilly said about `window.open` and window names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186531/discussion-between-jijil-kakkadathu-and-teemu).